# Error al consumir un servicio REST API con el metodo POST usando AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest

Estoy consumiendo un servicio REST API con angularJS y el metodo **`POST`**, pero al consumir el servicio me envia una peticion con el metodo **`OPTIONS`**. No entiendo por que? 
He leido y deje en el web.config del sitio las siguientes lineas:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://www.zonapagos.com" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <!--<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />-->
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
  </handlers>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

pero me sigue enviando primero la peticion **`OPTIONS`**

Tiene algo que ver con **`CORS`** pero no encuentro como solucionarlo

Comment: agrega el error de angularJS por favor sirve para usuarios que le pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hayes un error comun con angular integrandolo con Java o .NET, tienes dos opciones **la primera debes agregar la linea en el app.js**

```
.config(function(...., $httpProvider  ) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

**la segunda: modificar cada funcion de tu http**

```
$http({
    url: "tu url",
    method: "POST",
   params: {
      valor1: 'valor1',
      valor2: 'valor2'
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me funciono la segunda opcion, ya se envia en la primera peticion el metodo `POST`, pero antes yo tenia en _Content-Type_ asi: `'Content-type': 'application/json'` y ahora los datos dentro del json los deja vacios ó en 0. El json lo estoy enviando en el atributo `data`. Que debo hacer en ese caso?

Comment: actualice la respuesta agrege el parametro **params**