# Error 403 en Angular 4.3 Interceptor llama dos veces

Tags: rest, http, angular

Estoy consumiendo un servicio hecho con Java, el cual necesita que se le envie un jwt, generado previamente por un login.

Para ello he creado un interceptor en Angular 4.3

**vt-auth.interceptor.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
@Injectable()
export class VtAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authHeader = 'bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('JWT');
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }  
}
```

El problema viene cuando consumo un servicio externo, como http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts el cual, no requiere jwt, segun lo que veo en la consola de chrome, es que primero lanza la peticion sin el header 'Authorization', y despues repite la peticion, con el header insertado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago la llamada al servicio del backend en Java, en la primera llamada lo rechaza, dando un error 403 y por tanto, no dejando continuar la operacion. Por eso, no se donde esta el error, si en lo que yo estoy programando o en el servicio, que no acepta este tipo de peticiones.

Comment: creo que tienes este error https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/76782/28035 eso es en angular 1.x ahora como hacerlo en angular 2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/36048822/5695795

Comment: Veo el segundo enlace, pero desconozco como implementarlo. Como puedo agregar dos encabezados a un header en un interceptor?

Comment: fijate que recibe un json , poir lo tanto alli mismo!